# Как правильно работать с заголовками запросов в Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет. 
Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Разрабатываем интернет магазин на Nuxt.js, и сейчас застряли на проблеме с работой корзины.
У нас в общем такая схема. В Моего Vuex в функции nuxtServerInit отправляется запрос на состояние корзины. Состояние корзины хранится в сессии на сервере. 
В чем собственно проблема.
Нужно чтобы шла проверка, что если у меня в браузере висят куки( в куках должен храниться ключ сессии), если есть то, нужно чтобы запрос отправлялся с заголовком Cookie в котором будет название сессии и ключ. 
Т.е. сейчас проблема в том, что при отправлении запросов axios просто игнорит куки, и в хедеры не выгружает содержимое кук. Как быть подскажите?
В вообще нужно, чтобы в накст сервер ините спрева шла проверка, установлены ли куки? Если да, то отправить через axios Запрос в котором уже будут содержаться куки, а если же куки не установлены, то послать запрос через axios и потом из респонса этого запроса вытащить ключ сессии и запихать его в куки.
Или же заголовки как-то установить на уровне конфига Nginx???

Comment: Зачем в stateless приложении хранить на сервере в сессии? Вам подсказать как через axios отправлять и ставить глобально куки?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Да, было бы не плохо. Я уже разобрался с проблемой хранения состояния. Да, подскажите как глобально через axios куки ставить

Comment: чтобы глобально для аксиоса поставить куки их достаточно просто поставить в браузере.
Попробуйте `axios.get('some api url', {withCredentials: true})` если делаете запрос на другой домен.